# How to set -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact from Javascript programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I need to set the following CSS style programmatically using Javascript:

```
body {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
```

The problems I am running into are:

- I do not want to remove the other properties on the body style; I just want to add -webkit-print-color-adjust
- I can't seem to use document.body.style because of the leading hyphen in the name of this special style

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let body = document.querySelector('body');

body.style.setProperty('-webkit-print-color-adjust', 'exact');

// check how the style is now present in the DOM ( it is the "webkitPrintColorAdjust" property)
console.log( body.style );
```